# Converting Shapely MultiPolygon to Polygon: Technique doesn't always work

Tags: polygon, shapely, multipart, singlepart

In order to get the exterior coordinates I need to convert a shapely MultiPolygon to a Polygon. I do it like this:

```
if poly.geometry.type == 'Polygon':
    x, y = poly.geometry.exterior.xy
elif poly.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon':
    allparts = [p.buffer(0) for p in poly.geometry]
    poly.geometry = shapely.ops.cascaded_union(allparts)
    x, y = poly.geometry.exterior.xy  # here happens the error
```

This succeeds very often, but there are also cases where the Polygon obviously stays a MultiPolygon as the following error is still raised:

`AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'`

I've checked, however, that every part of the MultiPolygon is a polygon and not itself a MultiPolygon:

```
>>>>[p.type for p in poly.geometry]
['Polygon', 'Polygon']
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Can it be the holes in the polygon? I looks like this:
[image]

Comment: A MultiPolygon is a simple list of Polygons, therefore a lists has not "exterior", but every Polygon in the list has "exterior". If you want the Polygons use a for loop ([p.exterior.xy for p in Multi)]

Comment: Okay, I see, but what can I do then in order to get the exterior coordinates of the *MultiPolygon*? In my approach I am trying a union of the single polygons, but this seems to be not working here....

Comment: Is it possible that the API of shapely changed in the mean time? I don't see the attribute `geometry` in a `Polygon`, but `geom_type` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to understand the Shapely binary predicates:

1. If the two polygons intersects the result of `union` or `unary_union` (in red) is a Polygon therefore you can computes the exterior

[image][image]

2. If the two polygons are disconnected,  the result is necessary a MultiPolygon (in red with two polygons)

[image][image]

And if you work with Shapefiles, without topology, this may occur

A solution is to compute the Concave Hull but it is not really an union.

[image]

EDIT: Concave hulls can be computed using [shapely.concave_hull](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.concave_hull.html).

Comment: Okay, indeed, I found out that this is the case - and logic! Thanks a lot!

Comment: how do you compute concave hull?

Answer (score 0):

**object.convex_hull** is all you need

**Note:** This object is can be a MultiPolygon

Answer (score 0):

```
if poly.geometry.type == 'Polygon':
    x, y = poly.geometry.exterior.xy
elif poly.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon':
    x, y = [poly_item.geometry.exterior.xy for poly_item in poly]
```